# Exclude specific email address with regex

Tags: python, regex, email

I have this regex for extracting emails which works fine:

```
([a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])@([a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z])
```

however there are some e-mails I don't want to include like:

```
server@example.com
noreply@example.com
name@example.com
```

I've been trying to add things like ^(?!server|noreplay|name) but isn't no working.

Also by using parentheses as above will afect tuples with (name, domain) ?

Comment: Just check for the forbidden addresses before/after checking with regex. Regex is not needed for this.

Comment: Second @Czechnology... I don't think you should try and force something like that into your current regex - it would be much better to have a second, separate regex that tests for those emails

Comment: BTW your original regex fails to recognize many valid email addresses. For example, any email with a comment segment or any username with a '+' character in it, will not match, though they are valid [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822) addresses See [I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx)

Comment: @dbenhur mmm interesting, I'll check up those examples. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the results from your regex for any emails that match the bad emails list.

```
results = list_from_your_regex
invalids = ['info', 'server', 'noreply', ...]
valid_emails = [good for good in results if good.split('@')[0] not in invalids]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check for those email addresses after you extract them...

```
bad_addresses=['server@example.com', 'noreply@example.com', 'name@example.com']
emails=re.findall('[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])@([a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]', contentwithemails)

for item in emails[:]:
  if item in bad_addresses:
    emails.remove(item)
```

You have to do a slice of emails ( `emails[:]` ), because you can't do a for loop on a list that keeps changing size. This creates a "ghost" list that can be read while the real list is acted on.